# The four armed minifig

Tags: minifigures, shopping, minifigure-identification

How do you put together a four armed minifig?????

[image: Nadakan]

I really want one.

Answer (score 4):

The good news is: This Minifig is still available (as of March 2017)! The bad news is, he's only in two sets and they're both quite expensive. He's Nadakhan, the captain of the Sky Pirates in the Ninjago range. There is also General Kozu, but his set is even more expensive.

- [Misfortune's Keep](http://brickset.com/sets/70605-1/Misfortune-s-Keep)
- [The Lighthouse Siege](http://brickset.com/sets/70594-1/The-Lighthouse-Siege)
- [Samurai X Cave Chaos](http://brickset.com/sets/70596-1/Samurai-X-Cave-Chaos)

As Kevin points out in the comments, Lord Garmadon appears three times in the [LEGO Ninjago Minifigures series](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/themes/minifigures/products/the-lego-ninjago-movie-71019) (Garmadon, Volcano Garmadon (pyjamas), and Flashback Garmadon (suit and tie)), so it's possible the part is now more widely available.

The key part from [Nadakhan's body](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=njo195) you need is:

> [Torso, Modified Short with Armour Breastplate...](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11692pb02&idColor=0#T=C&C=80)

Or there are some other [options from earlier Ninjago sets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Torso,%20modified%20short#T=A) available as well.

Which accepts a standard neck post and has holes for the arms.

Comment: So what pieces would I use for the actual body?

Comment: You'd use a standard torso (body) for the bottom part, and then a "torso, modified" on top of that - they are custom designed to fit on the neck and shoulders of the standard body part.

Comment: there were also at least two in the CMF line for the Ninjago movie.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is [Z-95 Headhunter (75004)](https://brickset.com/sets/75004-1/Z-95-Headhunter) which has General Pong Krell, but it is also fairly expensive.

[image: 75004 set photo]